# Can I extract only integers from each line in a string and save them in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, integer

I have a string containing 3 lines that looks like this.

```
@ 544 000
* 600 000
‘7000...
```

I want to extract these numbers to a list as integers.

```
Numbers = [544000, 600000, 7000]
```

I've tried using a for loop splitting the data like this.

```
numbers = []    
for word in data.split():
    if word.isdigit():
        numbers.append(int(word))
print(numbers)
```

But the results were

```
[544, 0, 600, 0]
```

am I on the right track here,or do I need to split it some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `str.isdigit()` + `str.join()` (extract every character from the line and check it with `str.isdigit()`. Join every digit afterwards with `str.join()`):

```py
s = """@ 544 000
* 600 000
‘7000..."""

for line in s.splitlines():
    print("".join(ch for ch in line if ch.isdigit()))
```

Prints:

```
544000
600000
7000
```

Or as a list:

```py
numbers = [
    int("".join(ch for ch in line if ch.isdigit())) for line in s.splitlines()
]
```

---

EDIT: With added checks for lines not containing numbers:

```py
numbers = [
    int(m)
    for line in s.splitlines()
    if (m := "".join(ch for ch in line if ch.isdigit())).isnumeric()
]
```

Comment: @Kalween See my edit (I've added a check for lines not containing numbers).

Answer (score 2):

The same as @AndrejKesely with a regex:

```
import re

numbers = [int(''.join(re.findall(r'(\d+)', line))) for line in text.splitlines()]
```

Output:

```
>>> numbers
[544000, 600000, 7000]
```